# Building a rotatable lift in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a "cube" in Unity. This cube has a Trigger, when moving into it, the object gets grabbed into the air. This is working as a lift, you can see an example what I mean here. It is a small scene taken from Spyro 2.

https://youtu.be/f8wWMa4N5mE?t=643

The code I use is really small for now

```
private float liftSpeed = 10; // the speed, the object is flying up

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    Rigidbody objectRigid = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); // get the rigidbody from the object in the trigger

    if (objectRigid != null) // does it have a rigidbody?
        objectRigid.velocity = new Vector3(objectRigid.velocity.x, liftSpeed, objectRigid.velocity.z); // make it fly in the air
}
```

So I have a lift, that totally works fine. But I when I rotate my lift I want it to work aswell.

Some examples (my gamne is 3D)

[image: lift rotated by 45 degrees]

---

[image: lift rotated by 90 degrees]

So how can I make my lift work for all "rotations"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use transform.up to get the up direction of your lift, and then multiply by the lift speed.

```
objectRigid.velocity = transform.up * liftSpeed;
```

transform.up changes depending on how the object is rotated, so if your lift is rotated to the left, then the lift will carry objects to the left.

Comment: Sorry, I used this code and the player still gets pushed up in the air .. ? I thought your code was right but the player is still going up on Y

Comment: I rotated the lift by 55 degrees on X for tests

Comment: Are you using lowercase transform.up? And is the script attached to the lift?

Comment: This should work fine, the player should be moved along the `up` axis depending on the direction the lift is oriented as long as they are still in contact with the trigger object

Comment: @KevinH. yes and yes. This is really weird, I think your code should be fine ... don't get the mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can use the transforms [RotateAround](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) Method for a rotation like in the video clip.

```
Transform t = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
```

The given snipet lets the object rotate around it's axis, which is pointing up.

Comment: sorry, I don't want to rotate the player, I want the player moving along a lift, that is rotated by X degrees

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the player child of the lift OnTriggerEnter.
2. Move the lift as you do
3. You can rotate the lift using RotateAround function. The player should also rotate along with the lift, as it's a child of the lift now.
4. make player's parent to null when it's out of lift trigger using OnTriggerExit

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the problem.

The lift and the EndPoint will be Empty GameObjects. If you want the lift has a platform or a base you can add a GameObject as child of the lift with the shape you prefer.

You need to attach a Collider to the lift and set it as trigger.

Then you add the following script to the lift Empty GameObject

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveLift : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform end;

    float speed = 4f;

    bool liftActivated = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(liftActivated)
         {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            //To move up the lift
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, end.position, step);
            //To spin the lift
            transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, 2 * Time.deltaTime);

            //To stop spining the lift when it reaches the end of the path
            if(transform.position.Equals(end.position))
                liftActivated = false;
         }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        liftActivated = true;
        other.gameObject.transform.parent = this.transform;
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic=true;
    }
}
```

Then you should decide if once the lift reaches its destination it is the player who has to move out of the platform, or if you unparent it and let it fall down as the end of the trip